# facebook javascript permission dialog for email

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have a question.... i am actually developing a facebook application with FB javascript SDK. In my application I need email permission for further processing. i am using

FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("email");
but some how  the dialog doesn't appears... here is my code

```
 <script>
    appid = '*************';
    name = 'Palmchip Test App';
    href = 'https://apps.facebook.com/*********/';
    FB.init({
    appId:appid, cookie:true,
    status:true, xfbml:true
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
    alert("You are logged in...");
    FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("email", function(perms) {
           if (!perms) {
            alert("no access");
           } else {
               alert("accessed...");
           }
         });
    }
    else {
    top.location.href='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id='+appid+'&redirect_uri='+href+'&display=page';
    }
    });

</script>
```

the alert which says **you are logged in...** works fine but then nothing happens .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to upgrade to OAuth 2.0 `ouath: true`
2. You should use the new [OAuth Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/)
3. You should be aware when upgrading that [`FB.getLoginStatus()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) will return different objects: `response.authResponse`

Comment: i tried OAuth Dialog link and even using the exactly same code mentioned there i still face no response :( n after using the **Direct URL Example** i see a big Facebook icon on a page which i click and then i am directed to permission dialog allow dialog

Answer (score 0):

Try this code block

```
FB.init({appId: <?= APP_ID ?>, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth:true});

function getin(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            var regurl = "/login";
            location.href=regurl;

        } else {
            var regurl = "/logout";
            window.location.href=regurl;
        }
    }, {scope:'email'});

}
```

So when you call the **getin()** function , if the current user already gave you the email address it'll do nothing for him just will redirect him to **/login** url , but if the user is a new user then he/she will see a pop-up box asking for the email address once he/she allows that you can pull the email address using graph or fql. BTW response inside **FB.login** has the user id , access_toke and some more useful data so save that for further use.